# Preimages of a function: Is the following proposition true or false?

Tags: functions, logic, proof-writing

Let $g: ℤ \times ℤ → ℤ \times ℤ$ be defined by $g(m,n) = (2m, m – n)$.

Is the following proposition true or false? Justify your conclusion.
**For each $(s, t) ∈ ℤ \times ℤ$, there exists an $(m, n) ∈ ℤ \times ℤ$ such that $g(m,n) = (s, t)$.**

I understand the question, and I believe it is true. But I have no idea of what the steps are on how to prove it is true. I guess I should not have skipped the past couple of days. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** the first coordinate of the image point $(2m,m-n)$ is always even.

What happens if $s$ is odd?

Comment: If s is odd and m = s/2, then m would result in a fraction. Which means that m is not an element of Z, so the proposition is false? I guess I am a confused by the (m,n)∈Z×Z.

Comment: Yes, it is false. If $s$ is odd it can not be of the form $2m$ so any point with odd first coordinate is not on the image. So the functions is not onto.

Comment: The previous part of this question asked to Determine the set of all the preimages of (1, 1). Because 1 is odd, does that mean it is not on the image, therefore the set of preimages does not exist? Or would the set of preimages be empty. I answered it just as g(0.5, -0.5) but now I'm sure that is the wrong answer since 0.5 and -0.5 are not integers.

Comment: The preimage  of $(1,1)$ is the empty set, that is $g^{-1}(1,1)=\emptyset$. Be careful, $g^{-1}$ is not the inverse function here. It is a notation to preimage.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your insight definitely helped me with this problem. You have earned my upvote.